# ROS Answers SE migration: kubuntu + ROS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was ROS tried on Kubuntu? I am considering installing Kubuntu 11.04 and would be happy to know if anybody tried ROS in this or similar versions of the OS
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10446/kubuntu-+-ros/) by [obs](https://answers.ros.org/users/772/obs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should work without a problem. Kubuntu is just normal Ubuntu + KDE, and ROS works on Ubuntu 11.04.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4